# Cocoa Cover flow using NSBrowser

Tags: macos, cocoa, coverflow, nspopover

I have seen quote a few examples of implementing Finder with in the app. 
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/SourceView/

I would like to know, using the existing NSBroswer can one be able to show the same contents in a coverflow? I mean to say the horizontal navigation with the items being displayed on the top?

Thanks.